# What is the Python image viewer on OSX called?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, viewer

I am used to IDEs having their own image viewing system, but am making the move to using atom editor and terminal on OSX. When I run a python script, like `test.py`, and call the `plt.show()` function from matplotlib, the default Python Viewer appears, as shown in the following image. What is the name of this viewer?

[Python Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXtIH.png)

I want to research how to utilize the viewer better like how to load multiple images into the viewer, but do not know where to start. The name would help. Thanks.

Comment: You could try starting the `Activity Monitor` and sorting processes by process id, then viewing something in the Python aviewer and seeing what gets the highest process id. Maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see if not an image viewer, but the output of the chosen [Matplotlib backend](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend). Your image looks like the `MacOSX` backend, but you can choose various others depending on your matplotlib installation.